# .is(":visible") after find

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem detecting a visibility state of checkbox and I would like to ask you for a help.

I have a dynamicaly loaded part of the page, which looks like:

```
<div id="box">

   <div class="colored">
   <input type="checkbox" value="f01" name="mycheckbox">
   <!-- some content -->
   <div>

   <div class="colored">
   <input type="checkbox" value="f02" name="mycheckbox">
   <!-- some content -->
   <div>

  <!-- .... -->


</div>
```

This represents, shall we say, items in some gallery. Every class="colored" div can be VISIBLE or HIDDEN.
Lets say, it is the simple filter, like I want to have visible only class="colored yellow" divs

And now the core of the problem:
I need to loop through whole BOX element, find all checkboxes and by each checkbox, "ask him", if it is visible, and if true, check him.

Unforunately, this doesn't work:

```
function checkallfav() {
    $("#box").find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if (this.is(":visible")) {
            this.checked = true;
        }
    });
}

//And this doesn't work as well
function checkallfav() {
    $("#box").find('input[type=checkbox]').is(":visible").each(function () {
        this.checked = true;
    });
}
```

The problem is, that the FIND function returns the whole element, I tried 
Console.debug(this); and in firebug, the response was all html  element

So, please, anyone has a solution?

Comment: You need to use `$(this).is(":visible")`

Comment: As the two answers show, either of your methods *could* have worked, you just had slight errors in both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**:visible**](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector on checkbox itself. Using `:visible` on selector will filter out only visible elements and then `prop` can be directly used on those checkboxes.

```
$("#box").find('input[type=checkbox]:visible').prop('checked', true);
```

The code can also be shorten as

```
$('#box :checkbox:visible').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here `this` refers to native DOM object and they don't have `.is()` function its a jQuery function thus have to use with jQuery object. Thus `$(this).is(":visible")` should be used.

```
$("#box").find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
        this.checked = true;
    }
});
```

A simpler way to achieve is by using @Tushar's recommendation

Answer (score 1):

You could use `prop()` function parameter too:

```
$("#box").find(':checkbox').prop('checked',function(){
    return $(this).is(':visible');
});
```

This would by the way uncheck any hidden checkbox (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with `.filter()` method:

```
$("#box").find('input[type=checkbox]').filter(':visible').prop('checked', true);
```